# Conversion of weekly - string format data to weekly(7 day week) xts data frame

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a csv. file containing a prices series of a commodity from 1997 to 2018, in weekly - string format and it has exactly 52 observations per year. Which means, a week is defined as a seven day week.  I want to convert this to a new data frame of xts format, containing weekly(7 day week) timeseries data ( in order to be compatible with ugarch package). I am new to xts format and do not know how to convert.
Thank you very much in advance.

This is how my data look like;

```
 week        price
1997-week1    32.1
1997-week2    30.8
1997-week3    24.6
1997-week4    24.7
1997-week5    22.1
1997-week6    22.8
1997-week7    26.8
1997-week8    24
1997-week9    23.5
1997-week10   22.4
1997-week11   21.9
1997-week12   21.1
.
.
1997-week52   51.5
.
.
1998-week1    54
1998-week2    51.5
.
.
2018-week52  117.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you have is the file created by the Note at the end,
create a function, `week2index` which converts your week column to the form year + 0/52 for week 1, year + 1/52 for week2, ..., year + 51/52 for week52 and then with `read.zoo` create a zoo object with that index. Finally convert it to a ts series.

```
library(zoo)

week2index <- function(x) {
  d <- read.table(text = sub("-week", " ", x))
  with(d, V1 + (V2 - 1) / 52)
}
z <- read.zoo("jay.dat", header = TRUE, FUN = week2index, regular = TRUE)
tt <- as.ts(z)
```

giving this ts series (or use the zoo series z):

```
> tt
Time Series:
Start = c(1997, 1) 
End = c(1997, 12) 
Frequency = 52 
 [1] 32.1 30.8 24.6 24.7 22.1 22.8 26.8 24.0 23.5 22.4 21.9 21.1
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "week        price
1997-week1    32.1
1997-week2    30.8
1997-week3    24.6
1997-week4    24.7
1997-week5    22.1
1997-week6    22.8
1997-week7    26.8
1997-week8    24
1997-week9    23.5
1997-week10   22.4
1997-week11   21.9
1997-week12   21.1"
cat(Lines, file = "jay.dat")
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah Thank you very much for the quick reply. I actually want the final output as xts.format.As I understand, here, the final output is in in ts. format

Comment: xts does not support numerc format for the index.  You can use use zoo or ts both of which are provided in the answer.  I am not Ronak Shah.

Comment: .Thank you. sorry for the mistake!